# ¿Como puedo compilar una caperta con archvios .cpp y .hpp sin tener que escribir todos?

Tags: c++, gcc

estoy tratando de compilar en consola un proyecto el cual lo tengo separado en una subcarpeta llamada "include" la cual tiene archivos .cpp y .hpp; fuera de esa sub-carpeta tengo mi main.cpp.
seria algo asi:

carpeta_del_proyecto:

```
include: <-la sub-carpeta
    Archivo1.cpp
    Archivo1.hpp
    así hasta un total de 10 archivos mas
main.cpp
```

Intente compilar con el siguiente comando con el fin de no escribir todos los archivos, pero no funciona como pense:

g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp -L./include/ -o main.exe

existe alguna forma de hacer algo asi, o tengo que escribir el nombre de todos los archivos a compilar? Se me paso, es en windows 10

Answer (score 1):

puedes ocupar un archivo `Makefile` para poder quitarte toda esa carga de encima, lo malo es que estás en windows. así que tendrás que descargar el programa que ejecuta este tipo de archivos "`make`"

aqui te dejo unas preguntas relacionadas

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127524/how-to-install-and-use-make-in-windows

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481269/how-to-make-a-simple-c-makefile

los archivos make son muy utiles para proyectos que  contienen muchas dependencias

Comment: De hecho eso estoy haciendo, solo es el hecho de saber si se puede para evitar escribir los nombres uno por uno jajajaj